# Sizeof applied to parameter of incomplete array type

Tags: arrays, c, language-lawyer, diagnostics, incomplete-type

For this code:

```
int f(int x[])
{
    return sizeof x;
}
```

GCC produces:

```
warning: 'sizeof' on array function parameter 'x' will return size of 'int *'
```

Clang produces:

```
warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'int *' instead of 'int[]'
```

Question: if `x` has incomplete type (since the size is not present), then is it expected to have:

```
error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type
```

Extra: does it mean that `return size of 'int *'` is a GCC/Clang extension?

Comment: Array type is well defined in `C`. What do you mean, it is incomplete?

Comment: See here for what the array type does and when: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array. Your question explicitly answered by the lines: `If expression in an array declarator is omitted, it declares an array of unknown size. Except in function parameter lists (where such arrays are transformed to pointers) and when an initializer is available, such type is an incomplete type`. Take a note of "**Except in function parameter lists..**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array as an argument to a function is actually a pointer.  From section 6.7.6.3p7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Function Declarators:

> **A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
> type’’,** where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation. If the keyword static also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
> actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many
> elements as specified by the size expression.

This means that this:

```
int f(int x[])
{
    return sizeof x;
}
```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
int f(int *x)
{
    return sizeof x;
}
```

So `x` does have complete type and there is no error.  Both gcc and clang are being helpful in generating a warning as the result might not be what one expects.

Answer (score 2):

Despite appearances, the `x` parameter to your `f` function is *not* an incomplete type. It is a pointer (`int*`), because *any* array, when used as a declared parameter of a function is syntactically equivalent to a pointer to the array's first element.

Thus, the operand of your `sizeof x` expression is a complete type (pointer to `int`); the warnings given by the GNU and Clang compilers are merely 'reminding' you of this so-called "decay" of the array to a pointer.

To 'verify' the aforementioned *total* equivalence, add a forward declaration of the function, using `int* x` as the formal parameter – there will be (or *should be*) no further warning about that:

```cpp
int foo(int* x); // Foward declaration

int foo(int x[]) // Definition - No parameter type conflict
{
    return sizeof x ;
}
```

Comment: This is not wrong, exactly, but it does conflate the runtime (in principle) conversion of array *values* to pointers -- not just when they appear as function arguments -- with the translation time semantic interpretation of declarations of function parameters ostensibly of array type as instead having pointer types.  These do dovetail, but they are different effects, defined in different parts of the language spec, and, formally, having their effects at different points in time.

Comment: @JohnBollinger A good point, well made. I have removed the references to other types of array-to-pointer decay. (But, even in the case of a formal parameter, it is still 'decay', because information about the array's size is lost.)

Answer (score 1):

> Question: if `x` has incomplete type (since the size is not present),
> then is it expected to have:
>
> ```
> error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type
> ```

Yes, that would be the usual error message from gcc when one attempts to determine the size of an incomplete type, but that's not what is happening in the example code.

In the parameter list of a function declaration, all parameters declared to have array type -- including incomplete array types -- are adjusted to have corresponding pointer types.  This is described in C17 6.7.6.3/7:

> A declaration of a parameter as “array of *type*” shall be adjusted to
> “qualified pointer to *type*”, where the type qualifiers (if any) are
> those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation. [...]

That is a question of the semantics of the source code, not a runtime conversion, though it dovetails with the automatic conversion of array *values* to pointers that happens at runtime (in principle).

> Extra: does it mean that `return size of 'int *'` is a GCC/Clang
> extension?

No.  The warning message describes the semantics of standard C (since forever).

For what it's worth, I tend to prefer the form in your example when I plan to access the parameter as if it pointed to the first member of an array (by indexing it with `[]` or performing pointer arithmetic on it).  In particular, I always write the two-parameter signature of `main` as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Extra question: if `int x[*]` is can be used only in function declarations, then why C11 (and later) explicitly says "such arrays are nonetheless complete types"? Per "shall be adjusted" the `int x[*]` is adjusted to qualified pointer to `int`, which is complete type.

Comment: As I understand, if "qualified pointer to type" is a complete type, then it does not matter whether `int x[*]` is a complete type or not. Is that correct? How to ensure that `int x[*]` is a complete type? Any ideas?

Comment: @pmor, That such arrays are complete types is orthogonal to the adjustment of parameters of array type to parameters of pointer type.  That the result of such adjustments is (always) a complete type is not a factor.  The point of the adjustment, as far as I have ever been able to determine, is to enable function parameters to be declared with the same syntax as some of their corresponding arguments, yet also deal with the automatic conversion of array arguments to pointers.

Comment: @pmor, I have never figured out the point of the `int x[*]` form of function parameter declaration, but I note that it is not limited to the types of the parameters themselves. It can also be used in the derivation of other types at function prototype scope.  Possibly the anticipated use case is something like `int x[*][3]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array into a function, you are actually passing it's address as a pointer. Using `sizeof()` on the array will only return the size of a pointer. It will not produce an error as `sizeof(int*)` is a valid operation

Comment: Also, a pointer to an incomplete type is itself a complete type, so it legal to take the sizeof the pointer.